# How to connect Ubuntu to University LAN (Windows, Static IPs) to use Internet?

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet, dns, static-ip

I have always been a Windows user, and this is the first time I have installed Ubuntu 12.04. After installing Ubuntu, I am not being able to access college internet through my laptop. We have a wired network. All students have been provided with separate static IPv4 addresses like 192.168.0.xxx to access the college LAN, and 192.168.0.10 for college net. MacId registration was also done. We were given a port number to use for net connection. The subnet mask was 255.255.255.0. These were the 'only' settings I had to put for accessing the net connection and LAN connection, and all the DNS server, Gateway, etc settings were left blank/not touched in the Local Area Connection settings dialogue box.

Now that I have Ubuntu, when I tried to play an mp3 file, it asked for net connection to download a plug-in. But it was unable to connect as perhaps I have entered the wrong settings, or I am missing out on some of them. I am not being able to figure out what settings must be put where and what should be put for DNS server, gateway etc settings. Asking my administrator was useless. He had never even heard of Ubuntu, and advised me to revert back to Windows. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your static IP to your Ubuntu machine. My University is the same way. Here is how I did it:

- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19541/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-to-an-ubuntu-10.04-desktop-computer/

Basically all you have to do is open your internet connection manager and then edit your wired connection. You will need the following information which your IT department should be able to supply:

```
Your static ip like: 192.168.X.X
You netmask probably: 255.255.255.0
Your gateway which is like: 192.168.X.1
```

Then you might have to configure DNS depending on how your network is setup.

Comment: @user3087474 and John, It may also be prudent to contact the University to see if there's a specific IP that they can allocate, rather than just guessing.  At my University, the public IP one is assigned fluctuates based on the access point used (for WiFi), and on Ethernet ports it's static, but I have also been at Universities on which the Ethernet ports are dynamically assigned, so... yeah...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try it and revert back to you with the results.
And yes, I don't belong to a college which has any sort of IT department. All the departments are related to metal forming techniques. :)